# How to define hasMany relationships with Ember CLI 0.0.39+

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data, ember-cli

I have two models: `Survey` and `SurveyQuestion`

`Survey` has many `SurveyQuestion`s. Typically, you'd define your relationship like so (I'm using CoffeeScript BTW):

```
`import DS from 'ember-data'`

Survey = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr 'string'
  survey_questions: DS.hasMany 'survey_question', { async: true }
```

However, since using Ember CLI 0.0.39 (now 0.0.40), I get the error.

`No model was found for 'survey_question' Error: No model was found for 'survey_question'`

In order to get rid of the error, I had to do this:

```
`import DS from 'ember-data'`
`import SurveyQuestion from './survey_question'`

 Survey = DS.Model.extend
   name: DS.attr 'string'
   survey_questions: DS.hasMany SurveyQuestion, { async: true }
```

The problem with this approach is that `hasMany` doesn't know the `type.typeKey` for `SurveyQuestion` since it's not a string. `type.typeKey` in ember-data's `findMany` is `null`

How can I get this to work properly in Ember CLI where I need to do an `import` in order to resolve my dependency?

Comment: I believe the problem has to do with the underscore in the name of the element. I tried `survey-question` instead and that seems to work correctly with the `DS.ActiveModelAdapter`. Can models not have underscores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the underscore in the name. It should have been `survey-question.coffee`. Once I changed that, it could then be used in the `hasMany` as a string.

```
`import DS from 'ember-data'`

Survey = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr 'string'
  survey_questions: DS.hasMany 'survey-question', { async: true }
```

And since I'm using the `DS.ActiveModelAdapter`, it queries the correct URL: `/survey_questions`.